# Is it possible to build something that can measure water and oil in a tank with out being in the tank?

Tags: sensor, wireless, measurement

Say you have water and oil in tank....Is there any thing out there that can tell me how much water is in the tank and how much oil is in the tank???

Comment: What's the tank made of? Is it transparent?

Comment: Without you going in the tank? I would say, send your brother in :-). (Sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: Do you have a tank with both water and oil, and you want to know both how much water and how much oil? And how big a tank, and to which accuracy?

Comment: Please provide a clear and more detailed description of what you mean by "water & oil". Do you simply want the total combined amount? Are they mixed together (an emulsion) or in 2 layers? Water on top or oil on top? - depends on oil SG. What sort of oil is it.

Comment: If we know the type of oil, we can think of something.

Comment: And, what do you mean by "without being in the tank"? Is ANY inclusion unacceptable? Why so?

Comment: And, is the tank on stable foundations or is it expected to shake or experience vibrations (like in an automobile)?

Answer (score 2):

Since water will eventually separate from the oil if the fluid in the tank is kept still, then it is easy to use ultrasonic sensor.

E.g. You have a tank, that has water and oil already separated after some amount of time:

```
|          |  
|   water  |  
|__________|  
|          |  
|    oil   |  
|__________|
```

In this case You'd clearly see a reflection of sound wave from the conjunction of water and oil. Knowing the speed of sound in the oil and water You can measure the height and finally find the numbers You need.

Comment: Actually, you have live preview right below the text box where you type the answer.

Comment: If you take a moment to read the [markdown help](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) you'll know how to get ASCII art like I inserted into your answer.

Comment: Interesting approach. I wonder if we can use conductivity in a similar way.

Comment: Unless it's crude oil it's more likely that the oil will be on top.

Comment: True, more likely oil will be on the top, but anyway, got the idea.

Comment: Where is the sensor? Outside?

Comment: There is no certainty that well emulsified oil will separate in a useful time period relative to desired measurement period. Butter-margarine-water mix is solidish in my fridge, soft but uniform if left on bench and forms into layers in Australian outback (ask me how I know:-) ).

Comment: It doesn't matter where's the sensor since You'll get an echo wave on every junction of surfaces. Let's say a sensor is above the tank, so You'll get echo waves from: the sensor itself (that echo will be always visible, no matter if You point sensor anywhere or not), junction air-water, junction water-oil, junction oil-tank_bottom. If I didn't forget something...